# Docker-compose run container with all others

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given a `docker-compose-core.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  gradle:
    image: gradle:5.4.1-jdk8
    command: gradle build release

  kafka:
    image: kafka
```

And other(s) `docker-compose-{es6/es7}.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch{6/7}
```

I want to run:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:docker-compose-es6.yml 
docker-compose run --rm gradle
```

And starts ALL containers defined. I cant use `depends_on` because this must be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-core.yml -f docker-compose-es6.yml run gradle`, to run both files together with keys in the latter overriding keys in the former. So you can add on a key to `gradle` in `docker-compose-es6.yml` like so:

```
version: "3"

services:

  gradle:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch{6/7}
```

[The docs regarding merging multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)